# Wifi FASTER over Remote Desktop

Tags: wireless-networking, remote-desktop

I have a media centre PC - with a  ASUS PCE-AC68 3x3 Wifi Card. Win 7 x64.

The router is a TP-Link C3150 3x3.

I have a Acer Predator 17 laptop also on Wifi.

NETGEAR Pro6 NAS wired to router

Scenario - 
When I long on to the media centre via remote desktop on my laptop and copy a file from my NAS to the media centre I get 15 MB/sec in explorer.
When I copy the same file using the media centre as a PC I am lucky get get 1 MB/Sec!!!

I can sit in the bedroom next to the media center with the TV on (and showing the password screen) as I'm accessing it remotely through the laptop which is in the bedroom as well.

The moment I type in the password to the media center (killing the remote desktop connection) the SAME FILE COPY THAT WAS IN PROGRESS drops to 1 MB/sec.
Nothing else has changed - all devices are on, nothing else has been touched or moved!

So what happens in the Windows logon process that completely kills the file copy speed (note the adapter in Wifi settings still shows a 263 Mbit/sec connection) - still 2 bars etc..

It makes no sense!!

Help!
Thanks
Andy

PS
Tried disabling IP6
Run a malware scan
Reinstalled latest drivers
Windows is up to date